# Android Development: How can I run a thread while the app is not being used

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I came up with an idea for an application that needs to gather data and place it in a database while your either in another app or perhaps not even using your phone. I have tried using the Service class but from what I understood, Service is used for example, running a task that would slow the users interface. I want this but I also want it to run outside of the app. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Service is used for example, running a task that would slow the users
>   interface.

It could happen if the task you run in the service is heavy. Still you have the possibility to use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which makes use of a different thread to execute the task

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using IntentService and I tried to test it by printing out a Toast message. I realized that I was using the wrong Context so the toast would never print. I have it running now!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about using Service is correct. It is the only way to run thread in the background even when your app is not being used. You can set your service as a foreground service if you want to prevent Android from killing it.

Answer (score 1):

A **Service** is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform **interprocess communication (IPC)**. For example, a service might handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

More  you can read on [Official Android Documentation with Samples](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Answer (score 0):

first of all service has nothing to do with UI it doesnt slows UI as it runs on compeletly different thread.

You should consider using Intent service. here is the tutorial

http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android

Comment: By default a service actually runs in the main thread. An IntentService however doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use thread for background works. use service with **AlarmManagar**(AL) in service. In that you want to give some particular time period. so (AL) it will fire the service which you want to do in background, that means with out interacting with app. For more efficient work use **IntentService** instead of normal service. So it will more effective than the service.